# Problem connecting to Arduino with USB and audio

Tags: arduino, usb, audio

I have a project which uses an Arduino to detect tones generated by a laptop. The Tone Detector (TD) circuit is a very simple LM567 implementation designed to detect 10kHz. The circuit is powered by the Arduino, connected to the laptop headphone socket via a standard 3.5mm stereo audio cable. In testing, with Arduino externally powered, the circuit works fine - the laptop generates tones, which the TD detects and raises a signal to the Arduino.

[image]

The problem is that it doesn't work if a USB cable is connected between the Arduino and the laptop. I have tried all configuration variations I can think of, but the common factor is when the USB cable AND the audio cable are connected it doesn't work, and it seems the audio is simply not generated in this configuration. The target Arduino is a Leonardo, but the same problem occurs with a Uno.

All suggestions very welcome!

In response to questions, yes there is a common ground. The audio input for the TD is connected to 0v.

Tone Detector circuit:

[image]

Audio input is connected to Input and 0v; Arduino to 5v, 0v & Output.

It is clear from the comments that the issue is around connecting the audio and digital grounds together, the question now is, how can I solve this?

Comment: (1) Are all devices sharing a common ground? Disconnect the USB from the laptop and check for continuity from the USB COM through the Arduino, tone detector and audio lead to the laptop.

Comment: How is the ground wire in the audio cable connected?

Comment: If you connect a headphone in parallel to the circuit do you hear anything? Is the usb power enough for the arduino and TD circuit? Some computers do limit the usb power unless enumerated.

Comment: Usually laptops have a DC blocking capacitor that keeps the virtual audio ground (typically at 2.5v relative to power supply ground) from passing through the audio cable and shorting to earth ground. Not always though. Check what voltage a zero signal is relative to the shield on the USB cable (with the headphone jack unplugged). It should be zero, if it isn't, that is your problem.

Comment: Please post the schematics of the tone input device and how it connects to Arduino.

Comment: I confuse what work or not. let me summarize.
1. Arduino power on normally
2. TD got 5V powered.
3. Audio jack not produce a tone.
Is that right?
Did your PC notice audio plugged in?

Comment: @Mlab - Not quite - audio jack doesn't produce a tone _only_ when the USB cable is attached. All other configurations work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add an isolation transformer. Readily available on eBay with 3.5mm jacks, so I have just added one inline.

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/274391739005

Comment: That should not have been necessary.  It seems either that something in your earlier circuit depiction perhaps related to the coupling capacitor was not actually accurate.  Of course using an LM567 to detect output of a laptop and feeding the result back into the same laptop is a pointeless exercise unless as a stepping stone to a "real problem" you have neglected to mention.

Comment: I'll recheck the circuit & diagrams, but AFAIAA, it is accurate. This is just a test setup that demonstrates the problem in the simplest way - the elements (USB, LM567 etc) are part of a larger device.